# How to move shapes in Word to a bookmark position

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a shape in a Word document that I need to move to a bookmark location.

I tried to use the "left" and "top" properties, however, this does not work because to my knowledge, bookmark does not have "left" and "right properties.

I have tried to use cut and paste, but this does not work for shapes.

The following is the code to create the shape:

```
Set shp = ActiveDocument.Content.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl("Forms.CommandButton.1")

With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object
    .Caption = "Test"
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 44
End With

With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
    .Name = "Test1"
    .ZOrder (msoBringInFrontOfText)
End With
```

Comment: You should include any code you have in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a bookmark could you use an Absolute Position on the document somewhere?

```
        Dim Test1 As Shape

        Set Test1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes("Test1")

        With Test1
                .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
                .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
                .Left = InchesToPoints(6.889)
                .Top = InchesToPoints(0.374)
        End With


        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but the basic premise is still valid, and it is possible to insert a control at a bookmarked location (here a bookmark named 'bmShape') using VBA as shown below.

```
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oShp As InlineShape
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmShape").Range
oRng.Text = ""
Set oShp = oRng.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl("Forms.CommandButton.1")
oRng.End = oRng.End + 1
oRng.Bookmarks.Add "bmShape"

With oShp.OLEFormat.Object
    .Caption = "Test"
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 44
End With

With oShp.ConvertToShape
    .Name = "Test1"
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
    .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth
End With
```